# Optimization of raster to data frame function in terms of balance of RAM and speed in r

Tags: r, raster, ram, r-raster, profvis

## Problem

I am trying to use a model which requires me to transform, very large rastersStacks (around 10 million cells) to a data.frame, I am doing this on a shared server, and because of that, I am trying to optimize to reduce the RAM used, and hopefully not reduce the speed enormously. For that, I have written 2 functions, but I have not been successful. an RPUBS with the Results of my attempts is in this [link](https://rpubs.com/derek_corcoran/RasterToDataFrame), and a github with the rmd for that is [here](https://github.com/derek-corcoran-barrios/RasterToDataFrame) including the rds files for the profvis profiling.

## First function

First lets load the packages we will need:

```
# For spaital manipulation
library(raster)
# For benchmarking speed and memory
library(profvis)
# To parallelize operations
library(doParallel)
# To parallelize operations
library(foreach)
# For combination and looping
library(purrr)
# Data wranggling
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
```

### Tiling

The main way to reduce the RAM usage is instead of processing one big raster is to transform it into tiled rasters, for that I developed the following function:

```
SplitRas <- function(Raster,ppside, nclus = 1){
  TempRast <- paste0(getwd(), "/Temp")
  h        <- ceiling(ncol(Raster)/ppside)
  v        <- ceiling(nrow(Raster)/ppside)
  agg      <- aggregate(Raster,fact=c(h,v))
  agg[]    <- 1:ncell(agg)
  agg_poly <- rasterToPolygons(agg)
  names(agg_poly) <- "polis"
  r_list <- list()
  if(nclus == 1){
    for(i in 1:ncell(agg)){
      dir.create(TempRast)
      rasterOptions(tmpdir=TempRast)
      e1          <- extent(agg_poly[agg_poly$polis==i,])
      r_list[[i]] <- crop(Raster,e1)
      if((freq(r_list[[i]], value=NA)/ncell(r_list[[i]])) != 1){
        writeRaster(r_list[[i]],filename=paste("SplitRas",i,sep=""),
                  format="GTiff",datatype="FLT4S",overwrite=TRUE)
      }
      unlink(TempRast, recursive = T, force = T)
    } 
  } else if(nclus != 1){
    cl <- parallel::makeCluster(nclus)
    doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
    r_list <- foreach(i = 1:ncell(agg), .packages = c("raster")) %dopar% {
      dir.create(TempRast)
      rasterOptions(tmpdir=TempRast)
      e1          <- extent(agg_poly[agg_poly$polis==i,])
      Temp <- crop(Raster,e1)
      if((raster::freq(Temp, value=NA)/ncell(Temp)) != 1){
        writeRaster(Temp,filename=paste("SplitRas",i,sep=""),
                    format="GTiff",datatype="FLT4S",overwrite=TRUE)
      }
      unlink(TempRast, recursive = T, force = T)
      Temp
    }
    parallel::stopCluster(cl)
  }
}
```

My thought is that if you process each tile separately, you can transform into dataframes, one by one, and take out rows with NAs and thus reducing the RAM usage.

This function has 3 arguments:

- **Raster:** The stack you want to divide into tiles
- **ppside:** The number of horizontal and vertical tiles you will end up, the final number of tiles will be ppside*ppside, so if ppside is 3, you will have 9 tiles
- **nclus:** The number of clusters you will use for the parallelizing and speeding up your processing.

At the end of this function, you will have `ppside*ppside` number of tiles, saved in your working directory all called `SplitRasN.tif` where N is the number of the tile. Just as an example we will use the bioclimatic variables available in the raster package:

```
Bios <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=10)
```

I will test this transforming this into a different number of tiles as shown in the following figure

[image]

### Transformation from raster to tiles and then from tiles to data frame (Example)

so first we will use `SplitRas` function to get the 16 tiles using 4 cores:

```
SplitRas(Raster = Bios, ppside = 4, nclus = 4)
```

This will return the following files: `r list.files(pattern = "SplitRas")`

In order to get these tiles into one data frame with all the non-NA cells we need a list of the tiles, which we get with:

```
Files <- list.files(pattern = "SplitRas", full.names = T)
```

Which we can use then in the following function:

```
SplitsToDataFrame <- function(Splits, ncores = 1){
  TempRast <- paste0(getwd(), "/Temp")
  if(ncores == 1){
    Temps <- list()
    for(i in 1:length(Splits)){
      dir.create(TempRast)
      rasterOptions(tmpdir=TempRast)
      Temp <- stack(Splits[i])
      Temp <- as.data.frame(Temp, row.names = NULL, col.names = NULL, xy =TRUE)
      colnames(Temp)[3:ncol(Temp)] <- paste0("Var", 1:length(3:ncol(Temp)))
      Temps[[i]] <- Temp[complete.cases(Temp),]
      gc()
      unlink(TempRast, recursive = T, force = T)
      message(i)
    }
    Temps <- data.table::rbindlist(Temps)
  } else if(ncores > 1){
    cl <- parallel::makeCluster(ncores)
    doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
    Temps <- foreach(i = 1:length(Splits), .packages = c("raster", "data.table")) %dopar%{
      dir.create(TempRast)
      rasterOptions(tmpdir=TempRast)
      Temp <- stack(Splits[i])
      Temp <- as.data.frame(Temp, row.names = NULL, col.names = NULL, xy =TRUE)
      colnames(Temp)[3:ncol(Temp)] <- paste0("Var", 1:length(3:ncol(Temp)))
      gc()
      unlink(TempRast, recursive = T, force = T)
      Temp[complete.cases(Temp),]
    }
    Temps <- data.table::rbindlist(Temps)
    parallel::stopCluster(cl)
  }
  return(Temps)
}
```

Where `Splits` is a character vectors with the paths to the tiles, and `ncores` is the number of cores used for parallelization. This will result in the Data frame with the non-empty cells.

```
DF <- SplitsToDataFrame(Splits = Files, ncores = 4)
```

### Memory benchmarking (What I have tried)

First I generated Tiles for 1, 2, 4, 8, 10 and 12 ppsides

```
sides <- c(1,2,4,8,10, 12)

Home <- getwd()
AllFiles <- list()
for(i in 1:length(sides)){
  dir.create(path = paste0(Home, "/Sides_", sides[i]))
  setwd(paste0(Home, "/Sides_", sides[i]))
  SplitRas(Raster = Bios, ppside = sides[i], nclus = ifelse(sides[i] < 4, sides[i], 4))
  AllFiles[[i]] <- list.files(pattern = "SplitRas", full.names = T) %>% stringr::str_replace_all("\\./", paste0(getwd(), "/"))
}
```

```
setwd(Home)
```

And then profiled the function using only the sequential option of the function

```
library(profvis)
P <- profvis({
    P1 <- SplitsToDataFrame(Splits = AllFiles[[1]])
    P2 <- SplitsToDataFrame(Splits = AllFiles[[2]])
    P3 <- SplitsToDataFrame(Splits = AllFiles[[3]])
    P4 <- SplitsToDataFrame(Splits = AllFiles[[4]])
    P5 <- SplitsToDataFrame(Splits = AllFiles[[5]])
})
P
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(P, "profile.html")
saveRDS(P, "P.rds")
```

However as seen in the following figure (more detail can be found in the Rpubs linked above), RAM is more or less the same as before, but time went way up (That last part was expected).

[image].

### Some extra stuff

Finally when I tried benchmarking the RAM usage in parallel it seems as if profvis does not capture this. Any idea on how to check that out?

```
library(profvis)
PPar <- profvis({
    P1 <- SplitsToDataFrame(Splits = AllFiles[[3]], ncores = 1)
    P2 <- SplitsToDataFrame(Splits = AllFiles[[3]], ncores = 2)
    P3 <- SplitsToDataFrame(Splits = AllFiles[[3]], ncores = 4)
    P4 <- SplitsToDataFrame(Splits = AllFiles[[3]], ncores = 7)
})
PPar
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(PPar, "profileParallel.html")
saveRDS(PPar, "PPar.rds")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rasterToPoints`. Note that any rows that are all NA are omitted from the output.  Also worth pointing out that you can control how much RAM is used with `rasterOptions(maxmemory = XXX)`.

```
x = as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(Bios))
head(x)
#           x        y bio1 bio2 bio3  bio4 bio5 bio6 bio7 bio8 bio9 bio10 bio11 bio12 bio13 bio14 bio15 bio16 bio17 bio18 bio19
# 1 -37.91667 83.58333 -174   67   17 11862   37 -356  393  -31 -307    -7  -307   144    22     7    38    59    24    50    24
# 2 -37.75000 83.58333 -174   67   17 11870   37 -355  392  -30 -219    -7  -307   143    22     7    42    59    23    50    24
# 3 -36.91667 83.58333 -172   68   17 11872   39 -354  393  -29 -217    -5  -305   136    22     6    42    57    22    49    23
# 4 -36.75000 83.58333 -173   68   17 11887   39 -354  393  -29 -217    -5  -306   136    22     6    42    57    22    49    23
# 5 -36.58333 83.58333 -173   68   17 11877   39 -354  393  -29 -217    -6  -306   136    22     6    42    57    22    49    23
# 6 -36.41667 83.58333 -173   68   17 11879   38 -354  392  -29 -217    -6  -306   137    22     6    41    57    22    49    24
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to use a model which requires me to transform, very large
> rastersStacks (around 10 million cells) to a data.frame,

In stead, I would use `raster::predict`, or `terra::predict`; and perhaps run these with parallelization.

`terra` has a `makeTiles` method that may be useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RobertHijmans, that is interesting, how would you use de predict function for that! I am very intrigued by that idea!

Comment: You can do `predict(raster data, model)`  Perhaps with the `fun=myfun` argument of the predict function of model is not standard